# The directory does not exist

Tags: 8

#### TL;DR

In Report → Status, I’ve the following error:

`Writable (public download method)
The directory /var/priv_fls does not exist. You may need to set the correct directory at the file system settings page or change the current directory's permissions so that it is writable.`

**How can I solve this error?**

#### Full Story

In my webhosting at Forpsi, I’ve got FTP access to folder, in which there is `www` folder (let’s call this folder `web_root`). I’ve installed Drupal 8 in `web_root/www`. Then, I’ve added to `web_root` I’ve created a folder called `priv_fls`—for private files—and chmod’ed its permissions to 777 (I know it’s not secure). In `web_root/www/sites/default/settings.php` the following line: `$settings['file_private_path'] = '/var/priv_fls';` and Cleared all caches (in Drupal). Then the error above appeared.

It might be that it is not `/var/priv_fls` from Drupal’s point of view, but even tried to change it `/priv_fls` in `settings.php`, but the error remained.

**Update**

I emphesise that `web_root` is only a *substitution* for the ‘root’ folder to which my webhosting provider (Forpsi) gives me access. If I login to the server using FTP, this `web_root` folder lists the following files:

```
/> ls
drwxr-xr-x    9 66573      users            4096 Sep  5 20:10 .
drwxr-xr-x    9 66573      users            4096 Sep  5 20:10 ..
-rw-rw----    1 66573      users               7 Sep  1 02:39 .ftpquota
dr-xr-xr-x    2 0          0                4096 Jul 15 22:01 backups-forpsi
drwxr-xr-x    2 66573      users            4096 Sep 23  2010 data
drwxrwxrwx    2 66573      users            4096 Sep  5 20:10 priv_fls
drwxr-xr-x    3 66573      users            4096 Sep  1 12:54 softaculous
drwxr-xr-x    2 66573      users            4096 Sep 23  2010 stat
drwxr-xr-x    2 66573      users            4096 Sep 23  2010 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   10 66573      users            4096 Sep  4 19:40 www
```

But I can’t get the absolute path (`pwd` gives me `ftp://user@server.com:/>`; `ls ..` gives me same output as `ls`; both of which are useless from the point of getting the absolute path).

Anyways, Drupal is installed on **shared** webserver.

Comment: _It might be that it is not /var/priv_fls from Drupal’s point of view_ Given that you created the folder under a folder called web_root, it can't be that from _any_ point of view. That's a full (not relative) system path, so it'll need to be /path/to/web_root/priv_fls

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to get the absolute path (see the update in the question).

Comment: This is probably a question best suited for Forpsi support, but it's possible there's a Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow user who might know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`web_root` = `/web/htdocs4/username/home/`, where `username` is (at least in my case) my ftp login (they use the following convension: for domain `example.com` the `username` is `examplecom`)

#### Full Story

I’ve just accidently found out what is the absolute path of the `web_root`.

I installed [TCPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/tcpdf) module and enabled both TCPDF and TCPDF Example. The latter created a link `TCPDF example` in the second (right) sidebar, and when clicked that link, it showed me the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in /web/htdocs4/username/home/www/modules/tcpdf/src/TCPDFDrupal.php on line 16`